# Alias' aren't runnable/executable from a shell script? Mac OS X Sierra 13.x

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, shell

So this screenshot basically explains it

https://gyazo.com/1a9d621efa28c7994c3a2afbe0411a2b

I've got some alias' set up for opening a new tab within terminal, and doing other stuff, even an alias for running the debug shell script, but the `debug.sh` script simply uses an alias, `newtab`, to try and open a new tab, which works when just typing `newtab`, but it doesn't work, any neither do any other alias', from within a .sh or any other executable files, how do I fix this?

One thing I noticed was that I'm putting all my `export`'s and `alias`' into `/etc/bashrc` and not `~/.bash_profile` or the other ones, and I hardly see `/etc/bashrc` mentioned anywhere

am I doing it right?

Comment: For text inclusions, it is preferable to copy and paste into your answer, then select the insert and click the code `{}` button. This allows us to copy from your question into an answer. As well as reducing typing, it also prevents typing errors in the answer.

Comment: @AFH for text inclusions it is preferable to copy and paste into your answer?? Your answer?? Your/my question or?

Comment: When answering your question I needed to type `$scripts/debug.sh` and `$scripts/newtab.osx.sh`. As the world's worst typist, I would have preferred to copy and paste these from your question, to prevent errors, and I can't do this from an image. In this case there wasn't a lot of typing required, but it would have been very different if my answer had needed to include all your aliases, which a code insert in your question would have made easy, just as you can copy and paste if you need to quote any of the code in my answer in order to query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias expansion is done only from the interactive shell, but not within scripts so `debug` is expanded to `newtab`, but `newtab` is not itself expanded, since it is called from a script.

If you use exported functions instead of aliases, it will work:-

```
debug() { $scripts/debug.sh; }; export -f debug
...
newtab() { $scripts/newtab.osx.sh; }; export -f newtab
```

Exporting is necessary, because scripts run in sub-shells, although for the particular instance you cite it is only `newtab` that needs to be a function.

Functions can be used instead of aliases everywhere, but can do a lot more, such as adding an extra parameter to the end of the run string, a very simple requirement that aliases cannot do. In fact, they can do anything scripts can, but unlike scripts they run in the current shell, so they can change the environment and the current directory, for which a script needs `.` or `source` command to achieve.

Comment: nice as! what's the -f flag for?

Comment: To specify that it's a function: see `help export` or `man bash`.